# Java Swing Eclipse Program seems to compile; Wont run however

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

ive recently just got back into programming Swing and java in general and am quite rusty. My program im trying to finish is seeming to compile going by eclipse, but it wont run, its telling me it doesn't have a main type. And its not giving me an error notifications so im kind of stuck here at the moment.

I've never seen this error before so not sure what it is, or cant remember what it is if I have. Any ideas what im doing wrong or should fix to get this to run, thanks:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Timer;
import javax.swing.Timer.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class FamousLocations extends JFrame implements ChangeListener, ActionListener, Runnable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0;
    JMenuBar p = new JMenuBar();
    int Selected = 0;

    ImageIcon a = new ImageIcon("america.jpg");
    ImageIcon j = new ImageIcon("Japan.jpg");
    ImageIcon c = new ImageIcon("china.jpg");
    ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("ireland.jpg");
    ImageIcon t = new ImageIcon("thailand.jpg");
    ImageIcon ca = new ImageIcon("Niagra-Falls.jpg");
    Icon[] pics = {a,j,c,i,t,ca};
    private JLabel ImageLabel = new JLabel(pics[Selected]);

    String america = ("Grand Canyon, America");
    String japan = ("Kinkaku-ji (The Golden Pavilion) Kyoto, Japan");
    String china = ("Mount Huangshan, China");
    String ireland = ("Newgrange, Ireland");
    String thailand = ("Bangkok ,Thailand");
    String canada = ("Niagra Falls , Canada");
    String[] Box = {america, japan, china, ireland, thailand, canada};
    JTextArea lo = new JTextArea(Box[Selected]);

    String InfoGrand = new String ("desciption");
    String InfoHiro = new String ("desciption");
    String InfoMount = new String ("desciption");
    String InfoNew = new String ("desciption");
    String InfoBang = new String ("desciption");
    String InfoNiag = new String ("desciption");
    String[] Info = {InfoGrand, InfoHiro, InfoMount, InfoNew, InfoBang, InfoNiag};
    JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(Info[Selected]);

    private JTabbedPane tp = new JTabbedPane();
    public JSlider slider = new JSlider();
    private JPanel dropd = new JPanel();
    private JPanel checkb = new JPanel();
    private JPanel ImagePan = new JPanel();
    private JPanel InfoPan = new JPanel();

    private JCheckBox slider1 = new JCheckBox ("Show Slider" , true);
    private JCheckBox slideshow1 = new JCheckBox ("Slideshow", false);
    JComboBox com1 = new JComboBox(Box);






    public FamousLocations(){
       setTitle("My Bucket List");
       getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
       getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
       getContentPane().setSize(1000,1000);
       getContentPane().add(dropd);
       getContentPane().add(slider,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
       getContentPane().add(slider1);
       getContentPane().add(slideshow1);
       getContentPane().add(tp);

       slider.setValue(0);
       slider.addChangeListener(this);
       slider.setOrientation(JSlider.HORIZONTAL);
       slider.setPaintTicks(true);
       slider.setPaintLabels(true);
       slider.setMajorTickSpacing(1);
       slider.setMaximum(5);
       slider.setSnapToTicks(true);

       ImagePan.add(ImageLabel);

       checkb.add(com1);
       checkb.add(slider1);
       checkb.add(slideshow1);

       tp.addTab("Photo", ImagePan);
       tp.addTab("Description of Area", InfoPan);
       tp.addTab("Index and Options", checkb);

       ta.setLineWrap(true); 
       ta.setWrapStyleWord(true);
       ta.setEditable(false);
       ta.setVisible(true);
       ta.setSize(400,400);


       slider1.setVisible(true);
       slider1.addActionListener(this);

       slideshow1.setVisible(true);
       slideshow1.addActionListener(this);
       com1.addActionListener(this);
       com1.addActionListener(this);

       JMenu help = new JMenu("HELP");
       JMenuItem AL1 = help.add("how to use");
       JMenuItem AL2 = help.add("EXIT");
       p.add(help);
       this.setJMenuBar(p);

        AL1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"error");
                }
            });
        AL2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });

            setSize(250,250);
            setVisible(true);
    }


    public void change(){
        JTextArea ta=new JTextArea(Box[Selected]); 
        ImagePan.removeAll();
        ImagePan.add(ImageLabel=new JLabel(pics[Selected]));
        InfoPan.removeAll();
        InfoPan.add(ImageLabel=new JLabel(Info[Selected])); 
        ta.setLineWrap(true); 
        ta.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        ta.setEditable(false);
        ta.setVisible(true);
        ta.setSize(400,400);
        ImagePan.repaint();
        validateTree();     
    }

    public void run(){
            for(int y = 0;y==y+1; y++){
                slider.setValue(y);

                try{
                    Thread.sleep (1000);
                }

                catch (Exception e) {}
}
    }





    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

         if(e.getSource()==slider1) {slider.setVisible(slider1.isSelected());}

         else if(e.getSource()==com1)
         {Selected=com1.getSelectedIndex(); change();}

         else if(e.getSource()==slideshow1)
         {new Thread(this).start(); }
         }

    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
         if(e.getSource()==slider){Selected=slider.getValue();change();}
         }
}
```

Comment: `its telling me it doesn't have a main type.` - this is basic Java. To start executing Java code you need to have a `main()` method in the class the you pass to the JVM. Look at any example in your text book or the forum for an example. Typically when using Swing your main() method just creates the frame and makes it visible. You can also find examples in the [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html).

Comment: How could I forget that, so I added this, I dont think its right: 

public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
             Movies ex = new Movies();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

Comment: Looks reasonable. If it still doesn't work look at the tutorial link I provide you with. Start with the `FrameDemo` example code found in the section on `How to Make Frames`.

Comment: Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.